# unable to cast MS.Internal.NamedObject

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DisplayRecipeGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleRecipeCatalog}"   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True">
    <!---->
                                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="EditRecipe_Executed"></EventSetter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DisplayRecipeGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleRecipeCatalog}"   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"><!---->
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="EditRecipe_Executed"></EventSetter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

After using `CanUserAddRows="false"`, when I manipulate a data.

Ended up with error stating unable to cast `MS.Internal.NamedObject`.

Tried with below approach, it worked:

```
if (obj.GetType().ToString() != "MS.Internal.NamedObject")
    return this.Equals(obj as RecipeBase);
else
    return false;
```

Can anyone have any other approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone have any other approach?

You should use the `as` operator and check the result to determine whether the cast succeeded:

```
RecipeBase x = obj as RecipeBase;
if(x == null)
    return false;

return Equals(x);
```

Then there is no need to compare the string representation of the object's type with `"MS.Internal.NamedObject"`.

If you still want to do this for some strange reason, it's probably nicer to compare with the `System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` constant:

```
if(!(obj is System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder))
```